# How to insert various values or arrays inside of one array from a csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am need to compile a multidimensional array from a .csv file.
 
My .csv file is:

SEC|ID|TITLE|PRICE
Section 1
, ID 1, Title 1, 100
, ID 2, Title 2, 100

I need the array to appear like this:

```
[Section 1] => Array
    (
        [ID 1] => Array
            (
                [Title 1] => 100
            )

        [ID 2] => Array
            (
                [Title 2] => 100
            )

    )
```

with following sections and subarrays.

Currently I have this code:

```
$csvArray = array();


if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($data[2] >= "0") {
        $csvArray[][$data[1]] = Array($data[2] => $data[3]);

                }


    elseif ($data[2] < "0") {
        $csvArray[$data[0]] = Array();
            }

    }
fclose($handle);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csvArray);
```

The output of this is:

```
Array
(
[Section 1] => Array
    (
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [ID 1] => Array
            (
                [Title 1] => 100
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID 2] => Array
            (
                [Title 2] => 100
            )

    )

)
```

Can anyone help me get an output like I need by changing the csv file or the php? Or is it not possible? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the numbers as keys is for

```
$csvArray[][$data[1]] = Array($data[2] => $data[3]);
```

I think that changing to

```
$csvArray[$data[0]][$data[1]] = Array($data[2] => $data[3]);
```

should work (I've not tested it, but the error is quite clear)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great! I thought it should have a simple fix.